# Relation between set of Normal subgroups and set of Homomorphism images of a group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

let $G$ be any group.let $A$ is set of all normal subgroups of $G$, and $B$ is set of all homomorphic images of $G$.

Is there any type of relation between these sets.Mean some type of bijection like that.

For any normal subgroup $N \in A$ there is a homomorphic image $G/N \in B$ and conversely  for any homomorphic image $G' \in B$ there is normal subgroup $N=\ker\phi \in A$ where $\phi$ is homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$

Is this a bijection between A and B ?? or i am doing something wrong . please help.

Comment: I think you need to give a more precise definition of "the set of all homomorphic images of $G$". Clearly it is possible for there to exist distinct normal subgroups $M$ and $N$ of $G$ with $G/M \cong G/N$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Let $G$ be a group. Given a normal subgroup $N$ it is well known that $G/N$ is a group and $\varphi:G\rightarrow G/N$ taking $g$ to $gN$ is a homomorphism whose kernel is $N$.

On the other hand if $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ is a surjective homomorphism (so $H$ is an homomorphic image of $G$. Then by the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems) $N:=\ker \varphi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $H=G/N$.

Comment: how to prove this is bijection between $A$ and $B$ ? please explain

Comment: @Eklavya Take $N\in A$ by the first two lines there exists $G/N\in B$. For the other direction take $H\in B$ then by the last two lines $H=G/N$ where $N\in A$.  The first map is clearly the inverse of the second (and vice versa) so this is a bijection.

Comment: one  more thing do we seeing element of set $A$ and $B$  unique up to isomorphism ? or we treat distinct elements of set $A$ and $B$ as distinct objects?

Comment: $H$ is isomorphic to $G/N$. So I think it's only up to isomorphism (I'm not sure though).