# Prove that $ \pi$ induces bijection between set of all (normal) subgroups of $G$ which include $K$ and set of all (normal) subgroups of $G/K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $K \triangleleft G$ and $\pi \colon G \to G / K$ canonical epimorphism. Prove that $ \pi$ induces bijection between set of all (normal) subgroups of $G$ which include $K$ and set of all (normal) subgroups of $G/K$.

I don't know where to start. I have seen ([similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055832/relation-between-set-of-normal-subgroups-and-set-of-homomorphism-images-of-a-gro)) but it wasn't very helpful. I am beginner in this so I am having a hard time with tasks like this. Any hint helps.

Comment: This is the "lattice isomorphism theorem".